# how to access the application deployed in openshift3 (wildfly server)

Tags: docker, deployment, cloud, openshift, wildfly

I have deployed the application in my local wildfly server and able to access my application through the url (http://127.0.0.1:8080/dhana/.

I have deployed the same application in openshift3 starter (new) and the build & deployment is successful.

It showing me the service url as (  http://dhanabalan-dhana.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com), But when I tried to hit this link it shows as below

[image]

Looks like server is up and running, Can anyone guide me to access the application?
Do I need to specify any port (8080) here?

**Note:** ROOT.war is the deployed file

Comment: Your application is responding. Likely the way you structured your code or laid it out is wrong and isn't picking up things properly. Consider looking at the Wildfly example in https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html for an example of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I have ran the same code which is running fine in my local wildfly server without any issues.

Comment: How the S2I builder for OpenShift works may require how you layout your code be different. Don't assume that since it works locally that it will still work. Have a look at the example in that book and also look at the documentation for the Wildfly S2I builder. Which Wildfly S2I builder are you using?